# Vala uncompress gzip data

Tags: zlib, vala

I try to inflate tgz file in vala.
First, I make tgz file in following way.

```
import gzip
f_in = open('test.jpg', 'rb')
f_out = gzip.open('test.gz', 'wb')
f_out.writelines(f_in)
f_out.close()
f_in.close()
```

Next, https://gist.github.com/ce3d04afbf34f321959b

In windows case is compile ok, but execute failure.
In linux case is above gcc error.

Can you point out what is wrong with this code? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use gist, they expire.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce with vala master. Anyway bugs should be reported at http://bugzilla.gnome.org .